# Can a Microsoft Access form label control with Vertical=Yes be rotated the other way..?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using VBA to programmatically create a dynamic form in Access 2007. However, this post concerns a basic feature of Access, and is not specific to VBA. When creating a forms or report, the label control has the property `Vertical`, which if enabled displays the text rotated 90 degrees...in the opposite direction from what I would like.

The `Vertical` property rotates the text 90 degrees *clockwise*. Is there any way to make it rotate *counter-clockwise*..?? It seems goofy to rotate it that way, and I find it difficult to read and comprehend. In Excel, in Format Cells > Alignment > Orientation, it provides the ability to rotate in both directions from +90 to -90 degrees. Can Access do this..?

If the Access label control cannot do as I wish, I'm open to any and all suggestions, including the use of other controls such as MSForms, MSOffice, etc, and even layering with Subforms. But there's one technique I would rather *not* make use of: a graphical image that's been rotated. I tried it and it's rather beastly, especially with a gradient form background.

Here's a screenshot of what I mean. The first six labels are what Access gives me, but the last two I used GIMP to rotate selected areas of the image to show what I hope to achieve.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it cannot be done using MS Access built-in features. But you can use third party ActiveX components for text rotating at any angle, [here](http://access.mvps.org/access/modules/mdl0048.htm) is one of examples. Also you can use API functions for creating rotated text, see an example for instance [here](http://www.lebans.com/rotatetext.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, properties:other -> vertical

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please read the question again. OP knows about Vertical, they are asking how to reverse the direction.